# Is there an existing delegate in the .NET Framework for comparison?

Tags: c#, .net, sorting, delegates

The .NET framework provides a few handy general-use delegates for common tasks, such as [`Predicate<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfcke1bz.aspx) and [`EventHandler<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventhandler(VS.71).aspx).

Is there a built-in delegate for the equivalent of CompareTo()?

The signature might be something like this:

```
delegate int Comparison<T>(T x, T y);
```

This is to implement sorting in such a way that I can provide a lambda expression for the actual sort routine (ListView.ListViewItemSorter, specifically), so any other approaches welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You even got the names right :)

See [`System.Comparison<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx)

Comment: Lol.  Y'know I thought I looked for that.  Oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Look for: [`System.Collections.Generic.Comparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx)

Comment: Oops - had upvoted that, but Comparer<T> isn't the delegate type - that's System.Comparison<T> as suggested by Joel. Comparer is still useful, but it's based on the IComparer<T> interface.

Comment: Ohh bah humbug your right, darn Intellisense and my eyes;-) Could have sworn it looked like a delegate. I should have second guessed myself when i found it in System.Collections...thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Func?

```
void Example<T>(Func<T,T,int> comparereDel) {
  ...
}
```